# How to change height of options container in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-select

I have created a dropdown select in Next JS. By default, React-select gives a minimum height of the options container. I want to change. I did a lot of googling but nothing worked. Is there any way to change the height of the options container?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "", label: "" },
  { value: "1", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "2", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "3", label: "Vanilla" },
  { value: "4", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "5", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "6", label: "Vanilla" },
  { value: "7", label: "Chocolate" },
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
  const [size, setSize] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        defaultValue={selectedOption}
        onChange={setSelectedOption}
        options={options}
        isSearchable={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
```